NVME not detected by windows 11
I am desperately looking for an answer to a question I have been asking myself for MONTHS. After doing the windows 11 update one my computer, my NVME is not recognized anymore. It worked perfectly fine using windows 10 and even linux distros.
In windows 11, the nvme is simply nowhere to be found. I have no trace of it in the device manager nor in disk management.
I tried re-installing windows 11 several times, I always get the same result. I also tried updating the drivers from the device manager but no update was found. Also, the nvme does not appear when typing "list disk" in the command prompt.
A similar question is asked here: Nvme not recognized after Windows 11 update
but no solution is found and the comments did not help me much.
Here is my hardware configuration:
SSD (where windows is installed): Crucial BX500 2.5 SSD
NVME: Crucial P2 500GB 
Motherboard: Gigabyte Aorus B450 Elite V2

Do you know where the problem may come from ?

Is the NVMe device detected and listed in BIOS/UEFI setup?

Yes it is. I can also access nvme settings. I tried playing with these but without success.

Has it been verified any drivers required for the NVMe drive have been installed (normally this is an issue in WinPE when trying to install Windows to the NVMe drive)? Was Windows 11 upgraded or clean installed? If the latter, were the chipset drivers installed immediately upon exiting OOBE, prior to any other drivers, software, or Windows Updates (this is critical, as they must be installed first before everything else, since drivers/Windows Update depends on them, as they're hierarchical)?

Nothing seems to be installed for NVMEs at the moment, at least not when looking at the device manager (even after looking for updates). On their website, Crucial advise to install crucial storage executive from which we can install drivers, but the software does not detect the NVME either. The windows 11 install is an update from windows 10, not a fresh install.
